# How many circular arrangements are possible if at least one of the people will not have the same neighbours in any two arrangements in a round table?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

**Consider seven people seated about a round table. How many circular arrangements are possible if at least one of them will not have the same neighbours in any two arrangements?**

For answer , I used $ 6! = 720 $.
Since for circular permutation formula is $ \frac{n!}{n}$

But how do I find the number of circular arrangements are possible if at least one of them will not have the same neighbours in any two arrangements?

In the book , its given $360$ is answer.

Comment: What is the exact wording of the question as it is written? It seems to me that if there is one person who must have different neighbors in every arrangement, that the only thing that should really matter would be the two people to this person's left & right. There are only $\binom{6}{2}=15$ different ways to seat distinct people at this person's left & right. For each of these 15, yes there are $4!=24$ ways to seat the remaining 4 people, but it seems to me you should only get to pick 1 of these, since otherwise our no-same-neighbors person would have to repeat neighbors.

Comment: @indnwkybrd First paragraph is the exact question.

Comment: The question is worded a bit ambiguously, but you could interpret the requirement as: there must be 1 person who never has the same 2 people seated next to him, when everyone else at the table is seated in a given set of places. In this case, observe that 360 is exactly half of 720: this offers a hint. Index the people 1 thru 7; then, you can partition the 720 arrangements into 360 pairs of 2, where each pair has the same 2 people seated at 1's right/left; (a) the # on 1's left < the # on 1's right; (b) the other way around. To satisfy the condition you want just 1 of each of these 360 pairs.

Comment: By the way, this line of logic is equivalent to finding the answer as $\binom{6}{2}\cdot 4! = 15\cdot 24 = 360$ re: my earlier comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that another way to phrase the question is:  How many circular arrangements of seven people are possible if two arrangements are considered equivalent if each person has the same two neighbors?

The requirement that no person has the same two neighbors means that we need to count the number of distinguishable arrangements up to rotation and reflection.

Suppose Arjun is one of the seven people.  Relative to Arjun, there are $6!$ ways to arrange the other six people as we proceed clockwise around the table from Arjun.  This is the number of distinguishable arrangements up to rotation.  However, each person would have the same two neighbors if we had proceeded anti-clockwise around the table from Arjun and selected the same people in the same order.  Since reflections preserve the same neighbors, we must divide your answer by $2$.  The number of distinguishable arrangements of seven people at a circular table up to rotation and reflection is
$$\frac{6!}{2} = 360$$

Observe that a person will only have two neighbors if $n \ge 3$.  For $n \ge 3$, the number of circular arrangements in which each person has the same two neighbors is
$$\frac{(n - 1)!}{2}$$
When $n \leq 2$, each circular arrangement is its own reflection, so if $1 \le n \le 2$, there are $(n - 1)!$ distinguishable circular arrangements.

Comment: @trueblueanil  Keep in mind that two arrangements are considered equivalent if each person has the same two neighbors.  If the neighbor on your left is switched to your right, the neighbor to your right must be switched to your left.  When the neighbor on your left switches to your right, the person two seats to your left must switch to the position two seats to your right to retain the same neighbor since he/she cannot sit in your seat.  That forces the person who sits three seats to your left to move to the position three seats to your right, and so forth.

Comment: OK, with positions marked $0-6$, you are flipping people about the line $0-3.5\;$ Nice idea.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig ". .  . . ,  the number of circular arrangements in which each person has the same two neighbors is " , should not the sentence be like "in which each person DOES NOT same two neighbors"

Comment: @SubhamPoddar  The statement that two arrangements are equivalent if each person has the same two neighbors means that arrangements in which at least one person does not have the same two neighbors are not equivalent.  We are asked to count the number of arrangements in which at least one person does not have the same two neighbors, which means we must consider any arrangement in which each person has the same two neighbors as equivalent.

Comment: @SubhamPoddar  I should add that when we say that there are $(n - 1)!$ circular permutations that is up to rotation.  If we were to number the seats, there would be $n!$ arrangements.  However, if the seats are not labeled, we consider the $n$ arrangements that can be obtained from one another by rotation to be equivalent.  Therefore, up to rotation, there are $\frac{n!}{n} = (n - 1)!$ distinguishable arrangements, meaning ones that are not equivalent under rotation.  Here, we wish to find the number of arrangements that are not equivalent up to rotation and reflection.